# Miniconda keep redownload package on every environment update

Tags: python, pip, conda, miniconda

I need to install dependency in miniconda and declare all dependency in `environment.yml`. I need to install it via url using pip. Below is the content of my `environment.yml`.

```
name: my_env 
dependencies:
- pip:
    - <url>
```

The problem is every time I update my dependency using `conda env update`, it redownload the package. Is there a way so I don't need to redownload the package?

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can think of is by running two commands when building your project:

- explicitly install your package via `conda install ...`
- update your dependency via `conda env update`

to explicitly install your package use this command
`conda install --channel <url> <package_index_name> -y`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?